# Rails DateTime off

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So my rails app date time is off I believe.

I have a record that has a date: 2014-11-06 00:00:00

But it says the record was created_at: 2014-11-07 02:31:08

When today is still the 6th. Just night time. How can I fix this?

Comment: No need for snide remarks @user3591126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to rails c
2. find the record and call it r
3. r.created_at # it should be correct

you will find it saved in the db as UTC